# .jspx page won't deploy on generic jDeveloper app

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, weblogic, jdeveloper

I am having this problem with deploying and running an empty `.jspx` page on `weblogic server`. I have a generic web application in which I want to add just a page to it in the `ViewController`. When I create this page and right click over it and then click over `Run` I get the following error:

```
[04:36:57 PM] Deploying Application...
<Sep 14, 2016 4:37:07 PM CEST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1473863817655' for task '4'. Error is: 'weblogic.application.ModuleException: Could not setup environment'
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Could not setup environment
at  weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.activateContexts(WebAppModule.java:149    5)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.activate(WebAppModule.java:438)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:375)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:95)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.deployment.EnvironmentException: [J2EE:160101]Error: The ejb-link 'ejb_submit_batch.jar#PTBatchSessionEJB' declared in the ejb-ref or ejb-local-ref 'ejb/PTBatchSessionEJB' in the application module 'ViewControllerWebApp.war' could not be resolved. The target EJB for the ejb-ref could not be found. Please ensure the link is correct.
at weblogic.deployment.BaseEnvironmentBuilder.addEJBLinkRef(BaseEnvironmentBuilder.java:464)
at weblogic.deployment.EnvironmentBuilder.addEJBReferences(EnvironmentBuilder.java:496)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.CompEnv.activate(CompEnv.java:157)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.activate(WebAppServletContext.java:3144)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.activateContexts(WebAppModule.java:1493)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

```
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.deployment.EnvironmentException: [J2EE:160101]Error: The ejb-link 'ejb_submit_batch.jar#PTBatchSessionEJB' declared in the ejb-ref or ejb-local-ref 'ejb/PTBatchSessionEJB' in the application module 'ViewControllerWebApp.war' could not be resolved. The target EJB for the ejb-ref could not be found. Please ensure the link is correct.
at weblogic.deployment.BaseEnvironmentBuilder.addEJBLinkRef(BaseEnvironmentBuilder.java:464)
at weblogic.deployment.EnvironmentBuilder.addEJBReferences(EnvironmentBuilder.java:496)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.CompEnv.activate(CompEnv.java:157)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.activate(WebAppServletContext.java:3144)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.activateContexts(WebAppModule.java:1493)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I really don't know how to resolve this problem due to the fact that I am working on it for 3 days. Any suggestion to resolve. I am available to provide you will all required files and logs.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I should mention that if I comment this part in my `web.xml` the page launches perfectly ! But if I delete the commented part the error above appears.

```
<!--<ejb-local-ref>
<ejb-ref-name>ejb/PTBatchSessionEJB</ejb-ref-name>
<ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
<local>it.enigen.pt.batch.submit.ejb.PTBatchSessionEJBLocal</local>
<ejb-link>ejb_submit_batch.jar#PTBatchSessionEJB</ejb-link>
</ejb-local-ref>-->
```